# Opening same file twice using word interop

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

hi all am using a interop to open few files in MS-Word.It works fine.The problem is when i try to open a file that is already open does not work.A file in use dialog box appears in the task manager am able to access it only by clickng it in the task manager.How can i make it visible? Or can you suggest anyother way to do this?

[image]

```
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    WordApp.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsAll;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document WordDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
    WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(path, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing);
    WordApp.Visible = true;
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(WordApp);
```

Comment: If you only need to read from the file. you can try to open it in read only mode.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Why do you need to open the same file twice? Knowing the reason perhaps you can get better feedback :)

Comment: @Żubrówka no my application has a button to open a document in word.For the first time it works fine but when i click the button second time when the file is open application just stalls.A file in use dialog box appears in task manager but hidden in UI

Comment: When Word has a file open, I think it marks it as Read-Only on the disk -- maybe you could just check to see if a file is already marked as read-only and if so, tell Word to open the file as Read-Only? (I think if you specify the right arguments to tell it to open the file as Read-Only it won't stall your application.)

Answer (score 1):

If You need to open the file second time using only the read-only features(for example, if You use it as a template) then I dont see a reason You shouldn't just make a copy of it and open the duplicate every time You need it.

Maybe You can add additional info, so maybe someone has better suggestions to find solution!

Comment: Open as ReadOnly and use SaveAs to save the file. Works nicely for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load your files in another `AppDomain`, which you can unload after you don't need it

```
AppDomainSetup ads = new AppDomainSetup();
ads.PrivateBinPath = Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\\some.doc");
AppDomain ad2 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AD2", null, ads);
ProxyDomain proxy = (ProxyDomain)ad2.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(ProxyDomain).Assembly.FullName, typeof(ProxyDomain).FullName);
bool ok = proxy.DoMsWork("C:\\some.doc");
AppDomain.Unload(ad2);

    public class ProxyDomain : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public bool DoMsWork(string assemblyPath)
        {
            //Load your file and do work here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use this when unloading the interop:

```
WordObject.Quit
```

Releasing the interop object somehow does not allways work.

Check out additional info on .Quit http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.quit(v=office.11).aspx

You can make interop application to become visible using

```
WordObject.Visible = true
```

You should also bare in mind, that You should NEVER use office interop objects on server-side processes for document processing, generation etc, because it just is not ment for doing so. Interop object are memory and cpu hungry, realy unstable and crash a lot!

Comment: am not talking about unloading an interop.What i need is a mechanism to file whether file is already open in word or bring the file in use dialog box to the front.Thanks for your help :)